# regular expression for c# verbatim like strings (processing ""-like escapes)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping, verbatim-string

I'm trying to extract information out of rc-files. In these files, "-chars in strings are escaped by doubling them ("") analog to c# verbatim strings. is ther a way to extract the string?

For example, if I have the following string **"this is a ""test"""** I would like to obtain **this is a ""test""**. It also must be non-greedy (very important).

I've tried to use the following regular expression;

```
"(?<text>[^""]*(""(.|""|[^"])*)*)"
```

However the performance was awful.
I'v based it on the explanation here: http://ad.hominem.org/log/2005/05/quoted_strings.php

Has anybody any idea to cope with this using a regular expression?

Comment: And you are trying to do that using Perl?

Comment: No I'm using C#. (I understand Perl and use it alot, but i cannot use it for this application)

Comment: Then why does this have a Perl tag? :D

Comment: Because I thought it had something to do with perl regular expressions. I'm sorry if it caused any misunderstanding.

Comment: .NET has its own regex engine (which is in fact a lot more powerful than Perl's).

Comment: @m.buettner "*which is in fact a lot more powerful than Perl's*" - There you go, trying to start a fight.

Comment: @tylerl :D ... okay, probably not more powerful in terms of the (theoretical) languages it can match... since I guess balancing groups and recursion might be equally "powerful". But in terms of convenient features definitely. First and foremost, variable-length lookbehinds. And then it is the only engine that allows capturing of an arbitrary number of groups. That allows uses of the engine, which are simply not possible with a single regex in any other engine.

Comment: @tylerl thinking about it... balancing groups **might** be more powerful (in theoretical terms) than recursion, since you have multiple stacks. I think in .NET you could match something like `(a) (b) (c) abc` (for an arbitrary amount of characters), while with recursion you could only do that for `(a) (b) (c) cba`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got some nested repetition quantifiers there. [That can be catastrophic for the performance.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Try something like this:

```
(?<=")(?:[^"]|"")*(?=")
```

That can now only consume either two quotes at once... or non-quote characters. The lookbehind and lookahead assert, that the actual match is preceded and followed by a quote.

This also gets you around having to capture anything. Your desired result will simply be the full string you want (without the outer quotes).

I do not assert that the outer quotes are not doubled. Because if they were, there would be no way to distinguish them from an empty string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a lot simpler than you'd expect.  A string literal with escaped quotes looks exactly like a bunch of simple string literals run together:

```
"Some ""escaped"" quotes"

"Some " + "escaped" + " quotes"
```

So this is all you need to match it:

```
(?:"[^"]*")+
```

You'll have to strip off the leading and trailing quotes in a separate step, but that's not a big deal.  You would need a separate step anyway, to unescape the escaped quotes (`\"` or `""`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't if this is better or worse than m.buettner's (guessing not - he seems to know his stuff) but I thought I'd throw it out there for critique.

```
"(([^"]+(""[^"]+"")*)*)"
```

Comment: I think this has the same problem as the OP's attempt. But if you remove the second `""` and the last `*`, it should be pretty much as good as mine (even better, as it implements the "Unrolling-the-loop" optimization technique (@ridgerunner will sing a song about it, if he sees this anwer :D)). However, the `+`s require at least one non-quote character between the double quotes. You should probably make these `*`, too. (i.e. `"([^"]*(""[^"]*)*)"`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(?<=^")(.*?"{2}.*?"{2})(?="$)`
it will be maybe more faster, than two previous
and without any bugs.

Comment: "without any bugs", quite a claim, don't you think? ;) ... this will gladly match `"something"here"then""this""and"so"on"""`, but neither `"something"`, `"some""thing"`, nor `"some""thing""like""this"` (the latter because it does not end with a triple code, which is required by your regex)

Answer (score 0):

- Match a " beginning the string
- Multiple times match a non-" or two "
- Match a " ending the string

`"([^"]|(""))*?"`